# Moving MongoDB reports from one collection to another using Robo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm using MongoDB though Robo. I have a connection `A` with collection `a1` and a connection `B` with collection `b1`. I want to move some of the reports from the collection `a1` to collection `b1`. Is there an easy way to acheive it using Robo? I have read/write permissions. It feels like an easy task but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Import from the Global Toolbar**, or just right click a database collection in the Connection Pane and then go to the **Import Collections**.

[image]

Once the Import Wizard is open We'll click Another collection and go to next.

[image]

From here it's simply a matter of connecting to the source of desired collection

[image]

Now after it please define your source collection

[image]

[image]

[image]